# MSSQL SERVER 2005 Database table capacity

Tags: sql-server-2005

please tell me if frequently I am inserting data in table of MSsql approx 25000 records per day, and total rows in a table are 25,00,000. So in this case is any chance of loss or fail to insert data in sql table/database ????

Comment: Is it a matter of calculation or what ?

Comment: i think I am loss the insert transaction randamly.

Comment: Do you get any error when it fails?

Comment: No not yet but I miss the data some times when data come in bulk, as I think..

Comment: Please mark response as accepted if you are happy with it, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Please see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx and  [SQL Server: the maximum number of rows in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759244/sql-server-the-maximum-number-of-rows-in-table)
As stated in these links rows per table is only ***Limited by available storage***.

Also googling some questions is not a bad method to find answers.