# Thread was being aborted - while looping a lot of rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, timeout, response

I load a datatable which has aprox. 60.000 rows.

I loop these, and write them our like this to build a file:

```
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(lineItem);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);
```

When I iterate ~15-25.000 rows it works within 5 seconds, and the file is generated perfectly. However, there seems to be a limit where it suddenly takes a long time and then times out (?).

I get the error:

> System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
>   at System.AppDomain.GetId()     at
>   System.Threading.Thread.get_CurrentCulture()     at
>   System.String.IndexOf(String value)     at
>   Modules.DownloadReports.RemoveTags(String
>   s)     at
>   Modules.DownloadReports.WriteProductData(DataTable
>   products)

My timeout in the web.config is 3600 seconds, both for the application and SQL calls.

My code:

```
private void WriteProductData(DataTable products)
        {
            StringBuilder bld = new StringBuilder();
            try
            {
                //Column names
                const string str = "OrderId; ProductId; ProductName; SeriesName; BrandName; PrimaryCategory; Content; ContentUnit; Quantity; ListPrice; PlacedPrice; Status";
                bld.AppendLine(str);
                bld.AppendLine(Environment.NewLine);

                //Data
                string trackingNumber, productId, productName, seriesName, brandName, prodCategory, content, contentUnit, quantity, listPriceUnit, placedPriceUnit, status;
                string lineItem;
                string errorString = string.Empty;

                foreach (DataRow product in products.Rows)
                {
                  // initialize all the different strings

                  lineItem = string.Format("{0};{1};{2};{3};{4};{5};{6};{7};{8};{9};{10};{11};",
                                                trackingNumber, productId, productName, seriesName, brandName,
                                                prodCategory, content, contentUnit, quantity, listPriceUnit,
                                                placedPriceUnit, status);
                    //bld.AppendLine(lineItem);
                    //bld.AppendLine(Environment.NewLine);
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(lineItem);
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.ErrorFormat(ex, "An exception occured during writing of product data to BI report");
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                //Response.Write(bld.ToString());
            }
        }
```

**What have I tried...**

I've optimized the loop as much as possible, so the only thing left is building a string, concatinating by string.format.

I've also tried to use a Stringbuilder to build the big string, and then write it out in the end.

So my questions are...

- Why do I even get the Threas was being aborted exception? It takes aprox 75 seconds before it gives me the error, not 5 min
- ~15-25.000 rows take 5 seconds, so my logic says 60.000 should take max 15 seconds. What could go wrong here?

UPDATE:

I solved the problem by removing the cause of the long operation. There was a string operation which was quite slow.. And when it was called 3 times pr row, it made everything extremely slow.

However, that's not the root of the problem.. That's just a pragmatic fix which will work, until the data load is very bigger.

Comment: Checking this may help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829202/iis-request-timeout-on-long-asp-net-operation

Comment: Thanks for the link :) However, the timeout is 3660 seconds in my web.config

Comment: Is there any firewall that cuts you off?

Comment: Conceder follwing link may be this can help you..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759244/sql-server-the-maximum-number-of-rows-in-table

Comment: There is a great answer to this problem here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829202/iis-request-timeout-on-long-asp-net-operation

Answer (score 0):

try adding maxRequestLength="1048576" in web config this may also cause for the error you are getting.

Comment: Really good idea! Didn't think off that one. Unfortunately, it didn't do anything, no matter what I changed it to. Thanks a lot for trying.