# What Are Realistic Limits on SQL Server Table Size?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Our site has a few stats tables that log which users / page views / etc.

They're simple tables (a couple of id numbers and a datetime) but have lots of rows (e.g. 194,000,000) and the data print is getting quite big (6GB +).

Most activity is writing data (i.e. logging the stats) and performing count(*) operations by an indexed id field.

[image]

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759244/sql-server-the-maximum-number-of-rows-in-table) has some info about sqlserver 2008 limitations. But it mentions data in terms of TB and the max number of rows as "Limited by available storage". Does that mean there is no problem as long as we have enough disk space?

I can't shake the concern that these massive tables might lead to slower queries/ increased load on the server as they grow.

**My Questions**

1. Realistically, how big can a table grow before causing problems?  Is it *really* only limited by available storage? Are there any sensible limits (in GB / rows) given the table types I've mentioned?
2. Given that we only perform writes and count(*) queries, what type of
   problems could a massive table cause?
3. I'm guessing that count(*) queries will become more resource
   intensive the larger the table is.  Is that correct?  And to what
   extent?
4. Say for example a table was 500GB with 300 gazillion rows. Could
   that cause any other problems for sql server other than slower queries on the table itself?

Comment: I think the question you linked to covered it pretty thoroughly.

Comment: Not really. For example, it gives max capacity, but that might not be the same as 'relatively efficient workable capacity'. I don't know. Also the accepted answer suggests monthly table splits based on 100,000 new rows a day. That's every 3,000,000 rows. I'm wondering if I don't do that, how it might affect performance, given the setup as described in the question.

Answer (score 1):

There is so much variation in how tables are designed and what kinds of queries you can run over them that you're going to have a difficult time finding any guidance worth anything. My suggestion would be to load up a table with the amount of data you're expecting to have "live" in a non-production database and try the types of queries that you plan to do in your production table. If they work well, you're set. And if they don't, you'll see why they don't and perhaps be able to work around it with a different approach (i.e. different indexing, partitioning, etc).

Comment: I appreciate a lot depends on table and query design, that's why I detailed these at the beginning of the question.