# C# :- How to sort a large csv file with 10 columns. Based on 5th column (Period Column). Without memory

Tags: c#, sorting, out-of-memory, quicksort

How to sort a large csv file with 10 columns?
The sorting should be based on data type for example, string, Date, integer etc
Assuming Based on 5th column (Period Column) we need to sort. 
As it is large CSV file, Without loading the same in memory we have to do.

I tried using logparser, but beyond certain size it throws error saying
"log parser tool has stopped working"

So please suggest any algorithm which i can implement in c#. Or if there is any other component or code which can help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you actually mean by "without memory"?

Comment: You can first *index* file: create `Dictionary<string,int>` where key is 5th column value and value is a line number, sort that and then create a new file by loading corresponding line from source file (very slow) and appending it to a new one. Instead of line number you can process it as binary: remember offset and size of that line (will be faster).

Comment: Without memory means, without loading all the data in memory. As it is huge data it is end up with memory out of error. That is why mentioned we should not load the entire data in memory

Comment: The standard way to sort a file that will not fit into memory is an [external sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting). There's nothing in the .NET libraries for that. In my article at https://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=674, I show how to sort a text file. Sorting on the 5th column is a fairly simple extension of that, involving splitting the line and comparing the appropriate field. I suggest you start with that, as you know it will work. If this is something you have to do often, you can optimize your approach later.

Answer (score 1):

Do know that running a program without memory is hard, specially if you have an algorithm that by its nature requires memory allocation.

I've  looked at the External sort method mentioned by [Jim Menschel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/56778/jim-mischel) and this is my implementation. 
I didn't implement sorting on the fifth field but left some hints in the code so you can add that yourself.

This code reads a file, line by line and creates, in a temporary directory for each line a new file. Then we open two of those files and create a new target file. After reading a line from the two open files, we can compare them (or their fields). Based on their comparison we write the smallest one to the target file and read the next line from the file we used.

Although this doesn't keep much strings in memory it is hard on the diskdrive. I [checked the NTFS limits](https://superuser.com/a/446284/172195) and 50,000,000 files is within the specs.

Here are the main methods of the class:

#### main entry point

This take the file to be sorted

```
public void Sort(string file)
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(sortdir);

    Split(file);
    var sortedFile = SortAndCombine();

    // if you feel confident you can override the original file
    File.Move(sortedFile, file + ".sorted");
    Directory.Delete(sortdir);
}
```

#### Split file

Split the file in a new file for each line
Yes, that will be a lot of files but it guarantees the least amount of memory used. It is easy to optimize though, read a couple of lines, sort those and write to a file.

```
void Split(string file)
{
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(file, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        var line = sr.ReadLine();
        while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
        {
            // whatever you do, make sure this file your writed
            // is ordered, just writing a single line is the easiest
            using (var sw = new StreamWriter(CreateUniqueFilename()))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(line);
            }
            line = sr.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

#### Combine the files

Iterate over all files and take one and the next one, merge those files

```
string SortAndCombine()
{
    long processed; // keep track of how much we processed
    do
    {
        // iterate the folder
        var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sortdir).GetEnumerator();
        bool hasnext = files.MoveNext();
        processed = 0;
        while (hasnext)
        {
            processed++;
            // have one
            string fileOne = files.Current;
            hasnext = files.MoveNext();
            if (hasnext)
            {
                // we have number two
                string fileTwo = files.Current;
                // do the work
                MergeSort(fileOne, fileTwo);
                hasnext = files.MoveNext();
            }
        }
    } while (processed > 1);
    var lastfile = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sortdir).GetEnumerator();
    lastfile.MoveNext();
    return lastfile.Current; // by magic is the name of the last file
}
```

#### Merge and Sort

Open two files and create one target file. Read a line from both of these and  write sthe mallest of the two to the target file.
Keep doing that until both lines are null

```
void MergeSort(string fileOne, string fileTwo)
{
    string result = CreateUniqueFilename();
    using(var srOne = new StreamReader(fileOne, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        using(var srTwo = new StreamReader(fileTwo, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            // I left the actual field parsing as an excersise for the reader
            string lineOne, lineTwo; // fieldOne, fieldTwo;
            using(var target = new StreamWriter(result))
            {
                lineOne = srOne.ReadLine();
                lineTwo = srTwo.ReadLine();
                // naive field parsing
                // fieldOne = lineOne.Split(';')[4];
                // fieldTwo = lineTwo.Split(';')[4];
                while( 
                    !String.IsNullOrEmpty(lineOne) || 
                    !String.IsNullOrEmpty(lineTwo))
                {
                    // use your parsed fieldValues here 
                    if (lineOne != null && (lineOne.CompareTo(lineTwo) < 0 || lineTwo==null))
                    {
                        target.WriteLine(lineOne);
                        lineOne = srOne.ReadLine();
                        // fieldOne = lineOne.Split(';')[4];
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        if (lineTwo!=null)
                        {
                            target.WriteLine(lineTwo);
                            lineTwo = srTwo.ReadLine();
                            // fieldTwo = lineTwo.Split(';')[4];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // all is perocessed, remove the input files.
    File.Delete(fileOne);
    File.Delete(fileTwo);
}
```

#### Helper variable and method

There is one shared member for the temporary directory and a method for generating temporary unique filenames.

```
private string sortdir = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"));

string CreateUniqueFilename()
{
    return Path.Combine(sortdir, Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"));
}
```

#### Memory analysis

I've created a small file with 5000 lines in it with the following code:

```
using(var sw= new StreamWriter("c:\\temp\\test1.txt"))
{
    for(int line=0; line<5000; line++)
    {
        sw.WriteLine(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    }
}
```

I then ran the sorting code with the memory profiler. This is what the summary looked like on my box with Windows 10, 4GB RAM and a spinning disk:

[image: profiling summary with 60 seconds of wall time]

The object lifetime shows as expected a lot of String, char[] and byte[] allocations, but none of those have survived a Gen 0 collection, which means they are all short lived and I don't expect this to be a problem if the number of lines to sort increases.

[image: Object lifetime with only Gen 0 collections]

This is the simplest solution that works for me. From here easy alterations and improvements are possible, either leading to even less memory consumption, reduce allocations or a higher speed. Make sure to measure, select the area where you can make the biggest impact and compare successive results. That should give you the optimum between memory usage and performance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading CSV completely you can simply index it:

1. Read unsorted CSV line by line and remember *5th element* (column) value and something to identify this line later: line number or offset of this line from beginning of the file and size.
2. You will have some kind of `List<Tuple<string, ...>>`. Sort that

```
var sortedList = unsortedList.OrderBy(item => item.Item1);
```

3. Now you can create sorted CSV by enumerating sorted list, reading line from source file and appending it to new CSV:

```
using (var sortedCSV = File.AppendText(newCSVFileName))    
    foreach(var item in sortedList)
    {
        ... // read line from unsorted csv using item.Item2, etc.
        sortedCSV.WriteLine(...);
    }
```

Comment: List will not work as we have nearly 5 Crore (50 million) records. Even though you store the line number and the one column data in List, it will end with out of memory error.

Comment: csv-file with 50.000.000 lines? That's just few megabytes of memory, you sure it will not work? You can use database to store index list there, but then rather put a complete line. Table with 2 fields: 5th element and complete string. Then query sorted by first field records one by one and simply add them as they go into `sortedCSV`.

Comment: A CSV with 50 million lines of 100 characters each would occupy 5 gigabytes on disk. And if you loaded it into memory in C# would occupy 10 gigabytes (two bytes per character) *plus* string allocation overhead of something like 30 bytes per line. So figure another 1.5 gigabytes.

Comment: @JimMischel, that was a hard math for Friday evening, thanks for clarifications. If that's the case then the indexing will not work (same `OutOfMemoryException` as if loading complete csv-file into memory). Then perhaps database trick will do: 1) import csv-file into database (e.g. [mdf](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3876771/1997232)) 2) sort it 3) export into csv-file.