# Wide tables or lots of rows?

Tags: sql-server, database

I'm writing a schema to store Vehicle records. I want to store UP TO 62 pieces of information ("constraints") for each vehicle (year, make, model, aspiration, wheel base, body style, number of doors, etc). Most vehicles will only have 5 - 10 constraints populated.

I have about 12.5 million records to store. I've no option but to use a single database running on a single computer.

Each constraint is stored as an integer. Another provider, an industry standard, gives me labels for each of these values. For example a make of 54 is "Ford". The labels can update, but it's more common for new ones to be added.

There are no mandatory fields. Some companies catalog by year + make + model, others by engine, others by transmission, and some companies a mix of these.

I could make a single table with at least 62 columns. Each column would be indexed as they frequently are used for joining or used in a where clause. Or I could make a vehicle table that contains an Id, then make a constraints table that has the vehicle Id as a foreign key and the information for a single constraint for a single vehicle.

A single table has the advantage of being able to retrieve all constraints for one vehicle without any joins, but has the down side of having a NULL value in most columns of every record and having a LOT of indexes.

Is one design generally preferred over the other? I've done a little performance testing with my prototypes and don't see a huge difference in query times.

The vehicles are searched for and displayed hundreds of times per day from a website.

I'm currently prototyping in mssql 2008 r2, but could conceivably use 2012.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759244/sql-server-the-maximum-number-of-rows-in-table

Comment: Will the table be updated in overnight batches, or continuous single row transactions?

Comment: Mostly the table is updated live. Either the user updating individual records using the website, or the user causes a binary to run that may insert/update a few thousand up to tens of thousands of records (though they try to run those overnight).

Comment: As a general rule, I think it helps to think about problems like this in one of two ways. "If my data changes, how much effort will be required to update my tables?" For example, if "Ford" changed its name to "Foobar", as long as you're linking based on the same ID, minimal effort is required to change the data (in your case, you won't be updating 12.5mil records, just the relational table). The other thing to think about is, "Can I separate like data?" For example, does having a particular engine always mean having some other particular part? If so, you can store one value relating to both.

Comment: I have found that, with the same data, and the query returning the same records, the single table design is a LOT slower when returning results. Several times slower. I remember Pinal Dave saying that he found when you have a lot of columns which only contain NULL values it has a negative impact on query performance. He also mentioned it shouldn't, but testing shows that it does. I wonder if I'm making the same observation.