# What is the table record limit in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I'm up to a little over 200,000 records in an error log table so I was just wondering.  Thanks.

Comment: *Table record limit*? Do you mean *total number of rows*? If so, 200K isn't even a drop in the bucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are some of the [Maximum Capacity Specifications for SQL Server 2008 R2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server)

- Database size: 524,272 terabytes
- Databases per instance of SQL Server: 32,767
- Filegroups per database: 32,767
- Files per database: 32,767
- File size (data): 16 terabytes
- File size (log): 2 terabytes
- Rows per table: *Limited by available storage*
- Tables per database: Limited by number of objects in a database

Duplicated from: [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759244/sql-server-the-maximum-number-of-rows-in-table)

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/maximum-capacity-specifications-for-sql-server

Not really an answer, but I'd suggest looking at this documentation